# Do children's mispronunciations influence the development of a language?

Tags: language-change, language-acquisition

Having read [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/380677/why-do-some-nicknames-have-no-apparent-relation-with-their-original-counterparts) question about how alternative names develop for a given name (Bill for William, Peggy for Margaret etc.) It seemed reasonable to me to assume that at least some of these develop due to children having issue pronouncing their (or someone elses) name and thus being either taught simplifications by their parents or creating their own by mispronouncing the name in a specific way (for example "Pája" pronounced /paːja/ for "Pavel" /pavɛl/ is a valid nickname (though diminutive) in the Czech language and at least in the case of my daughter was a mispronunciation she came up with on her own trying to repeat the standard name).

Are there any studies on whether/how children's pronunciation errors effect language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are such studies.  Notably, Jakobson's [Child language, aphasia and phonological universals](https://books.google.com/books/about/Child_Language.html?id=i2gUutbrJLkC), and David Stampe's *The acquisition of phonetic representation* in Chicago Linguistic Society, vol 5.